# Changing the SWT Look and Feel

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I hava a Java App build with SWT, my problem is that the App is used on different systems so my app looks different depending on the Operating system.

The most users use thin clients and the app is running on a windows 8 server so the app got the classic Win2000 Design.

Is there any way to change the look and feel of the App / modify the widgets to a Standard design?

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: The main feature of SWT is to use the components of the underlying OS, and therefore the appearance of the components if that of the OS... One could do custom painting, however it is not what SWT is there for...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto I allready read about this but changing to another framework like javafx takes aprox ~1-2 Years. Culd you explain me the "Painting" a bit more?

Comment: I would suggest recreating the GUI in Swing, using a specific LaF, like Nimbus...

Comment: As i previously said, Switching to Swing or javafx isn't a option.  The program is huge and it takes Years to switch everything.  i need a way to fix this without switching to another GUI framework

Comment: The fact that SWT was selected as the API to use for the user interface suggests that the application was *designed* to have the native look and feel of the platform. What is there to "fix"?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou That right but this decision was taken around ~10 Years ago where Design and usability wasn't a big thing like it is today.

Comment: @Ice Drawing/painting everything yourself might take ~1-2 years as well to implement. You could go with the suggested answer which would involve switching to Eclipse RCP, which would be less of a change than switching to Swing/Java FX.

Answer (score 0):

SWT has supported theming via CSS for some time. I haven't actually done anything with it, though, but you should peruse the Wiki pages like https://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/CSS for details.

Comment: This is really an e4 RCP thing. I'm not sure it could be used for a plain SWT app as it has dependencies on lots of Eclipse plugins.